# Importar backup do sql server de outro servidor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Não consigo importar um backup (.bak) no sql gerado em outro servidor, fala que o banco de dados nao é igual o que estou tentando importar e tals, sendo que coloquei o mesmo nome.

Alguem sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Olá seja bem vindo ao SOpt  ! você poderia [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/123725/edit) sua pergunta , e nos dizer mais detalhes ? você pode começar includo a mensagem de erro que  foi exibida ao tentar importar  por exemplo .

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente está tentando restaurar um backup de uma versão superior em um SQL Server com versão inferior, por exemplo, seu backup é do SQL Server 2014 e está tentando fazer o restore no SQL Server 2008.